# Why is the update so awesome?

Tags: discussion

I mean, we really don't deserve it. It's awesome. Good work everyone, high-fives all around. Cheers (for those of you from across the pond, so-to-speak).

Comment: This is like the bleeding Houses of Parliament. "Would my colleague, the right honourable Member of Parliament for Nether Wallop, like to tell the House just how awesome we are, and how proud we are of our Glorious Leader"...

Comment: I thank the right honourable Member for Saskatoon for his excellent and insightful question.  Indeed, this government has a long standing policy for the promotion of awesomeness ...

Comment: Um, why don't we really deserve it? And indeed, why is it so awesome? In other words, what makes you say that? I'm genuinely curious...

Comment: Well, I don't know, I guess I don't feel like I deserve it, maybe you guys do.  But for the most part, considering that this is a free website, and that we're just a bunch of cross-eyed mathematicians, I'm not sure we deserve it. And w/r/t your second question, I'm still figuring that out. It certainly is pretty!

Comment: Oh, but for one thing, I'm really excited about the ability to edit comments, and do this: @ToddTrimble (did that work?)

Comment: Agreed, ability to edit comments is nice. If you're asking did the notification to me work, then "yes". And I'll say I had a positive exchange with SE support wrt to getting my account properly up and running, so that's a good sign as well. Oh, @JonBeardsley.

Comment: Yeah, so happy about tagging people in comments, though other people may not be so happy about my ability to do this...

Comment: For comparison: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/19/nothing-good-with-the-upgrade

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Well, Anton and friends worked pretty hard to make this happen, so they deserve a fair bit of credit here...

But mostly, it's this guy's fault:

[image: Super "Geoff" Dalgas]

He's been busting his rear for quite a while now to make sure everything works, and here pushing midnight he's *still* at it, his supper presumably cold on the dinner table and his wife in tears.

So if you see something you like, take a moment to raise your beer in the direction of Oregon and toast ol' Geoff.

Comment: Thanks to all the SE mods who've been so helpful over the last 24 hours getting everything up and running again. It's been a great start to 2.0!